# Push-уведомления работают некорректно, если на экране есть ПИН-код

Tags: java, android, push-уведомления

**Суть проблемы:** если на экране устройства есть ПИН-код, графический ключ экрана Android, или что-нибудь подобное, то по клику на *Push* просто вызывается `MainActivity` приложения. Если ключа нету, то открывает нужную  `Activity`.

**Код** моего `GCMListener`:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    String id = data.getString("news_id");
    String message = data.getString("message");
    Random random = new Random();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SpecificNewsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("newsId", id);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, random.nextInt(), intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(random.nextInt(), notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

В чём может быть ошибка ?

**Дополнительно:** Выяснилось что такая проблема только на Китайских телефонах (Meizu, Xiaomi например).

Comment: А если приложение остановить (через менеджер приложений например) и потом открыть через нотификацию - нормально отрабатывает?

Comment: @KoVadim Надо протестить, не помню пробовал так или нет.

Comment: @KoVadim Если выгрузить - работает. Причем странное дело, на нексусе 4 работает нормально с пин кодом экрана, а но маоем ксяоми - нет. Не знаете что это может быть ?

Comment: Я бы для начала распечатал содержимое intend и посмотрел внимательно. вполне возможно, что сторонний лаунчер все портит.

Comment: @KoVadim Проверил, интент отрабатавыет нормально и айтем который пришел сразу помечен как прочитанный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если кто еще столкнется с таким. Вопрос решился просто - запросы на сервер перенес из активити в которой был фрагмент, в сам фрагмент. Без этого на ксяоми и мейзу активити падала на этапе транзакции фрагмента в фрейм лейаут.